# Offline Payment Method

Tags: magento2.2

What is a proper way to implement offline payment method in Magento 2.2.*?

I did it old style like in module `magento/module-offline-payments` and it is working.

My payment model extends `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod`.

I wonder that `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` is deprecated and a suggestion is that custom payment method should extend `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter` but I don't want to make integration with any payment provider gateway.

In Magento 2 guides I found only integration with the third-party approach:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html

Sample:

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-payment-method-using-adapter-class-magento-2/ Magento Standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the AbstractMethod, what Magento wants you to do is either implement a virtual type of the façade you mention, or implement the interfaces directly.

- Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface
- Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodInterface

Most of the massive amount of methods are simple getters/setters, and AbstractMethod comes to the rescue by providing basic implementation of that.

However, Magento no longer likes inheritance - it's bad for tracking dependencies and can lead to complications with testing.  Instead they now prefer composition.

You can read more about the pros and cons of [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) on wikipedia.

You can still utilize the façade by following the tutorial.  Obviously you don't perform authorization, capture, or voiding so you can set false to those on the virtual type, and you shouldn't have to worry about implementing commands for them.

Comment: Hi @navarr, but what about the config in di.xml for the offline payment method ? Do we need to write anything about them also ??